# consulta en donde utilice las tablas necesarias que permita generar el siguiente resultado:

Tags: mysql, sql, tablas, union

Tengo que unir estas 2 tablas en una consulta

Mi primera tabla : tbl_socio

[image: TABLA SOCIO]

Mi segunda tabla : tbl_libro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos evidenciar que se muestra el tercer registro de los campos (nombre, apellido y telefono) de la tabla socio y el campo titulo y dias de prestamo de la tabla libro: esta imagen es la que me dice como tiene que quedar la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDIT: Hice este codigo pero solo me muestra los campos y no el registro que quiero que se vea

```
Select soc_nombre,soc_apellido,soc_telefono,lib_titulo,lib_diasPrestamo
From tbl_socio s, tbl_libro l, tbl_tipoautores t
Where t.copiaAutor=s.soc_numero and t.copiaISBN=l.lib_isbn
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla que relaciona a las 2, "tipoautores"

copiaISBN y copiaAutor son las llaves foraneas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. De las tablas que pones no hay una columna por la cual se puedan relacionar, así que (digamos) te hace falta una donde se indique que socio tiene actualmente el libro. Apoyate con el DBA para guiarte en como y donde estan relacionadas las tablas. Las que muestran digamos son de catálogo solamente.

Comment: Hola primero debes tener algo que una a la persona con el libro, una tabla que los una ejemplo una tabla que se llame SocioLibro donde metas el id de persona y id de libro, asi poder relacionarlos

Comment: utilicé una tabla que tiene llaves foraneas en relacion a la tabla socio y libro, pero no me muestra el registro que se muestra en la imagen

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor coloca tu consulta aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/ para asi ayudarte mejor

Comment: Nos falta esa tabla que une estas dos tablas...

Comment: Muestra que tiene la tabla tbl_tipoautores  que es nueva para nosotros

Comment: Listo @JosueVargas ya añadí imagen de lo que contiene la tabla tbl_tipoautores

Comment: Creo que no haz entendido, para unir a una tabla con otra deben tener algo en común, asi que talvez somos nosotros los que no entedemos... como unes en tu lógica un libro con un socio?

Comment: Debería haber una tabla de prestamos que relacione todas, las tablas que has indicado no parecieran que se pueden relacionar.

Comment: el libro es pedido por prestamo por un socio, es decir X socio pide un libro y como muestra en la consulta o imagen de arriba, El socio Ana Lopez tiene un libro de titulo Agua con 3 dias de prestamo

Comment: Perfecto @AndresRozoQuevedo pero donde dice que **Ana Lopez** tiene el libro **Agua** con 3 días de préstamo? que no sea la consulta final.. osea donde tienes registrado eso?